# Is there a way to balance the panning of an audio file?

Tags: logic-pro, audio, audio-editing, balance

I am using Logic Pro as my DAW, and I have an audio file that has a signal completely panned to the right side. So, I decided I would turn the pan knob to the left, but of course, there is no audio since the signal is completely panned to the right.

I want to be able to convert the signal to the left side as well, that way the audio file can play out of both left and right sides. Is there a way to do so? Can I fix the binaural panning? And if so, is there a way to convert the audio signal to the left *in Logic Pro* itself?

If you need clarification, please let me know. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120017/discussion-on-question-by-asa-matthews-is-there-a-way-to-balance-the-panning-of).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out!

In the left inspector channel strip (this is where you will find your plugins), select "Gain" ("Stereo", not "Dual Mono"). When you receive the Gain pop-up menu,  turn on "Mono", and the audio should now play out of both sides.

Comment: Try the same process, but without the phase invert- you should get the same result, assuming the information provided in your question is accurate.

Answer (score 5):

So, this is actually a *mono file* that has erroneously been rendered as single-channel stereo. So one fix is to convert it back to mono, which can then be used like any other mono file (panned to either side). Any DAW worth its money, or even its freeness, will have an easy way to do that. (Logic is IMO *not* worth its money, but still pretty sure it can do that.)

Alternatively you may be able to set up the *track* on which you have the file as mono, which should have the same outcome without actually changing anything about the file.
In modern DAWs, there's really no reason why you should be bound to having either mono or stereo tracks – any track should be able to support any number of channels, and re-route them at will. (This is at any rate trivially possible in [Reaper](http://reaper.fm/).)

Or you can use a dedicated *stereo manager* or *channel/matrix mixer* plugin. The former should have some kind of *stereo width* control, which should allow you to select how far to each side the channels actually appear. The latter allows you to just directly select how loud each input channel appears in each output channel.

Comment: Clarification still needed from the OP as to whether this is an intentionally stereo file, or mis-filed. OP claims it's binaural, so it would be far better to shift the pan law than lump it into a mono channel. Flip the channels or reverse the panner, preserving anything, ambience etc, that might actually still be in the other.

Comment: +1 for the good information, but I think your opinion on Logic is not needed

Comment: Isn't Logic one of the cheapest DAWs out there?

Comment: @Tetsujin if it really were a _binaural_ signal then nothing in it could possibly be panned 100% to one side. That's why I didn't even discuss that direction, but you're right that we should not just ignore details in the question, even ones that are probably just down to terminology confusion. Why don't you add an answer describing the binaural case?

Answer (score 0):

Original question -
***Is there a way to balance the panning of an audio file?***

Let's take you audio file, a WAV file made as a mono sample.
There are a tone of FX that handle panning, delay, reverb, and more that you can apply to the channel that sample resides.

There's your answer.

The best audio panning software should be found on 3rd party audio units.  So this will allow you to control the width and timing within the plugin.  Having effects software hooked up to a mixing board, midi device, or usb device will let you adjust settings by turning knobs or using a mixer.  Analog control makes some experience far more enjoyable than being restricted to a digital console (window based).  The lord knows how annoying that can get
.

Do you want me to start name dropping audio units that you can try out? I don't mind :)

Comment: Logic Pro actually helps with editing the panning. But I appreciate the help! :)

Comment: No, there are a ton of synths, sequencers, beat machines I'd be happy to share with you. I personally think are the best software around. Don't tell me you're already loaded to the max? If so, I don't want to waste your time. You need to keep your mind open to other newer software too. If you get stuck using the same studio software your sound will start sounding all the same. Collaborating with other producers can be difficult. Some environments aren't tailored for making new friends anyway. I congratulate the ones who can do it anyway. Doesn't hurt to ask for help either.

Comment: A DAW is the single most versatile instrument there is.  You don't need the next biggest plugin to make interesting music.  People made interesting music for centuries with the same old piano.  And you definitely don't need any extra software for simple utility tasks like OP wants to accomplish.